# How to bind command+s to save file on macOS?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, macos

I have a Macbook. I want to save files by pressing command + s (this should happen if it is in insert mode or not, and I want it to go to non-insert mode after it is saved).

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is this on `vim` on the terminal (also like iTerm2 etc.) or on MacVim? On terminal, you can't tell whether "command" key was pressed AFAICT, so I don't know if you can really get this done on terminal `vim`...

Comment: If it's on MacVim, you can use `<D-s>` for Cmd+s in mappings (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979313/9447571)

Comment: Note iTerm uses `cmd+s` for `Save Selected Text...` to a txt file. Similarly, Terminal.app has mapped it to `Export Text As...`. So you have to free the mapping first. This is actually not a question for vi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/387897/can-i-use-the-cmd-key-in-terminal-vim-at-all. I am not sure whether all answers can be recommended. Answer by romainl is probably not what you want to hear but should be considered. If you want to use bindings like `cmd+s` for the transition to vim, I'd recommend to  use macvim for the beginning. In the long run you should get used to `:w`, `ZZ` and similar.